# data segment too large while compiling

Tags: c++, c, embedded, microcontroller, 8051

Here, I am passing an array of bits to some other function.
Since, array size is too large, it throws an error saying "data segment too large" while compiling.

I have newly edited the code. But, the error: data segment too large still exists

This is the code:

```
char TxBits[]={0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,     
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,
               0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

 int nTxBits = sizeof(TxBits)/sizeof(char);

void data(char *TxBits,int nTxBits, int loopcount)
{

  int i;

  for (i = 0;i < nTxBits;i++)
  {

    gpio=TxBits[i];    
    wait(loopcount);
  }

}
```

So, I am thinking of converting bits in an array to bytes and passing to function. May I know how to proceed? open to suggestions.
Kindly reply

Comment: `void data(char TxBits) {` => `void data(char[] TxBits) {`. And `i < nTxBits` won't work.

Comment: I have defined nTxBits as:int nTxBits = sizeof(TxBits)/sizeof(char);

Comment: @sss put code inside backticks `like this` to make it readable

Comment: Is `data segment too large` the exact error message ? Because you have indeed an error in your code (`void data(char TxBits)` shoud be `void data(char *TxBits)`), but the message suggests a problem of memory model (small or tiny) that old MS/DOS compilers like TurboC++ used to issue.

Comment: And C and C++ are different languages, so please choose your own (here my advice would be C) or explain why the question concerns both.

Comment: Yes, " 'DATA': SEGMENT TOO LARGE " is the error popping up while compiling

Comment: @sss At this point we need to know, at least: What paltform? Which compiler?

Comment: The array doesn't look very big. What happens of you reduce the `TxBits` array so say 8 elements ? Maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I cannot imagine that this array makes the data segment too large, even on an arduino. You can check http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CorruptArrayVariablesAndMemory for a discussion of object sizes, types and where they are stored. There is a possibility that declaring objects `const` will make them end up in read-only memory which may have more space, but I have no practical experience what else needs to be done in the build process to achieve that.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It depens on the rest of code. Maybe there are other arrays or big RAM allocate dtsructures. BTW OP could try to change the declaration to `const char` to move array to flash memory.

Comment: @LPs Yes, flash was what I thought too. Perhaps you have practical advice for the OP about that? And -- if there is indeed a large array which the OP didn't tell us about I'll be kinda mad ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I'm trying to help him answering to his comments of answer.

Comment: @LPs I am using Silicon labs IDE

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider yeah there is another huge array in a config file. Sorry for not letting know before

Comment: On your 8051, you have 127 byte of data segment. As suggested you could declare `TxBits` as `const char`. This will put the array in the code space.

Comment: @sss So I think we got to the bottom of it, and I'm only a little bit mad.... ;-).

Comment: @sss BTW, I don't know Silicon Labs IDE and compiler, but probably there is somewhere the option to set the memory model used by application. Take a look [HERE](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/an143.pdf) it could drive you.

Comment: Using C++ on a 8051 core is like trying to squeeze a dull elephant into a rusty Lada from the 1980. Just my personal opinion of course.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for the solution. It worked for me.

Comment: @Lundin 'C++' and '8051' in the same sentence without the phrase 'don't even think about it'.  Strange:(

Comment: @MartinJames Personally I would prefer to squeeze an energetic, not yet housebroken chihuahua into a modern SUV (C on ARM).

Answer (score 2):

From your code I reckon you're working with some micro-controller so I'm not sure if you're serious about the C++ tag or not. If you are, this is a C++-style solution which uses `std::bitset` (specialised container for dealing with bits which will require less space):

```
std::bitset<134> foo (std::string("01010101010101010101010100101010101010101010101010010101010101010101010101001010101010101010101010100101010101010101010101010100000000"));

void data(const std::bitset& bitset, int loopcount) {
  // if C++11 
  for (auto& bit : foo) {
    gpio = bit;
    wait(loopcount);
  }

  // if C++98
  // for (int i = 0; i<bitset.size(); i++) {
  //   gpio = foo[i];
  //   wait(loopcount);
  // }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need this:

```
void data(char *TxBits, int size)  // size of the number of elements of your table
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0;i < size; i++)
  {
    gpio=TxBits[i];    
    wait(loopcount);
  }
}
```

Calling the function

```
data(TxBits, sizeof(TxBits) / sizeof(TxBits[0]);
```

To get the number of elements of an array we use `sizeof(TxBits) / sizeof(TxBits[0]` where `sizeof(TxBits)` is the number of bytes the array takes in memory and `sizeof(TxBits[0]` is the size of one element of the array.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the OP incorporated your suggestions in his post now with the last edit? I.e. if his problem persists, this does not solve it.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider it seem so. But anyway the OP's original code was clearly wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> I am passing an array of bits to some other function

No, you are passing an array of bytes, each byte having the binary value 00000000 or 00000001.

In order to save memory, you should store bit values as actual bits and not as bytes:

```
uint8_t TxBits[]=
{  0x55, // 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
   0x55, // 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
   0x55, // 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
   0x00, // 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0x20, // 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
   ...
};

size_t nTxBits = sizeof(TxBits) / 8;
```

You should also avoid the `char` type whenever doing arithmetic, since it has implementation-defined signedness.

Also if this is a small microcontroller system, you should allocate the data in ROM instead of RAM whenever possible. That is: `const uint8_t TxBits[]`.

Comment: so having changed the TxBits array as above, I need to transmit each bit inside a byte with MSB as first to Data Tx() function. Can you let me know how to proceed?

Comment: @sss Study binary and hex numbers to begin with. IMO everyone should be doing that before even considering to take on programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your Parameter is not declared correctly. Replace  this:

```
void data(char TxBits)
```

by this

```
void data(char [] TxBits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
void data(char TxBits)
```

Should be

```
void data(char *TxBits, size_t nTxBits)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0;i < nTxBits;i++)
    {
        gpio=TxBits[i];    
        wait(loopcount);
    }
}
```

You can call it by:

```
data ( TxBits, sizeof(TxBits)/sizeof(TxBits[0]) );
```

In this specific case, you have a `char` array, and you can also write:

```
data (TxBits, sizeof(TxBits));
```

Comment: I have edited the code according to the comments. Still, the error persists

Comment: @sss what is your platform? Try to change `char TxBits[]` to `const char TxBits[]`

Comment: I am using Silicon labs IDE for embedded application

Comment: @sss ok, but which MCU? How much RAM? I'm guessing you finished your space to allocate the whole array...

Comment: I am using C8051F930 on a development board

Comment: @sss I think the proper solution is to laugh Silabs in the face everytime they try to peddle you some 1980s technology. But even Silabs have ARM cores nowadays, there should be no reason for you to use that old crap.